# Accesing Property of object using a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Im trying to access a property of an object using using a variable which could change

```js
var i = '16';

var object = {
        "15" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
        "16" : [ 1, 3 ],
        "17" : [ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
        "18" : [ 1, 3, 4 ]
}
console.log( object['i'] )
```

using the variable gives undefined however using

```js
console.log( object['16'] )
```

gives you the array of that propery.

Does anyone know how i could work around this

Comment: `'i'` is a string not the variable `i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove quotes around your variable

```js
var i = '16';

var object = {
        "15" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
        "16" : [ 1, 3 ],
        "17" : [ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
        "18" : [ 1, 3, 4 ]
}
console.log( object[i] )
```